# Vue Initialise component from REST API data

Tags: vue.js

I want to make an API call from which the component's data gets initialized:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
        const fetchURL = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data`;
        response = await fetch(fetchURL)
        return await response.json()
    }
  }
</script>
```

This approach doesn't work because `data()` can't be async. What's the right idiom to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialize an empty array called items inside the data option and use the `created` hook to update it :

```html
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
     return{
       items:[]
     }
    },
   async created(){
       const fetchURL = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data`;
        response = await fetch(fetchURL)
        this.items= await response.json()
    }
  }
</script>
```